# JQuery AJAX File Upload Error 500

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I'm trying to do a file upload using JQuery's AJAX thing, and it keeps giving me the error 500.

```
$(function() {
    $( 'form' ).submit
    (
        function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'photochallenge/submit.php',
                data: new FormData(this),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    Materialize.toast(data, 4000);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    );
});
```

I am also using this PHP code to process the file upload:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = null;
$uploadOk = 1;
$response = "Please choose an image";
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["pic"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        $response = "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }


    // Check file size
    if ($uploadOk == 1 && $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        $response = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {

    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        //find target file
        $found = false
        $tmp = 0
        while(!$found)  {
            $target_file = $target_dir . $tmp . ".png";
            if(file_exists($target_file))   {
                $tmp = $tmp + 1;
            }   else    {
                $found = true;
            }
        }

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            $response = "Thank you for your submission!";
            shell_exec("python log.py ".$_POST["firstname"]." ".$_POST["lastname"]." ".$target_file);
        } else {
            $response = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
}

echo $response;
?>
```

Unfortunately, I cannot release the link to where the actual problem is, but hopefully this code is enough to help solve the problem. If any other details are needed, please do not hesitate to let me know.

Comment: i would start with permissions on the file you are trying to use in the ajax call. After that check permission on any directory you are trying to write to, the web server needs write permissions.

Looking at the code specifically, shell_exec looks like a function many hosts would want to disable in php.ini,

Comment: is it http 500 error or some internal logic - 500 error?

Comment: check server's error log. You are probably uploading file above limit.

Comment: So what does the error message say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using ".htaccess", the issue may be in the `shell_exec` that may be crashing the application, if you are using something as fast-cgi.

Comment this line and perfom your script:

```
shell_exec("python log.py ".$_POST["firstname"]." ".$_POST["lastname"]." ".$target_file);
```

Using comments in PHP:

```
//shell_exec("python log.py ".$_POST["firstname"]." ".$_POST["lastname"]." ".$target_file);
```